# Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.IWebAuthenticationBrokerStatics.authenticateAsync has been deprecated

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

I'm developping an application using Cordova/WinJS. It works fine when I tested on Windows Phone 10 Emulator, but I had problem on the Windows Phone 8.1 Emulator. The console showed this warning:

> "The method
>   Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.IWebAuthenticationBrokerStatics.authenticateAsync
>   has been deprecated. AuthenticateAsync is unavailable for releases
>   beginning with Windows Phone 8.1. Instead, use AuthenticateAndContinue
>   or AuthenticateSilentlyAsync"

How should I fix this warning?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the error message, use `AuthenticateAndContinue`. The way how this API is handled differs on Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8.1 because on the phone the user is redirected out of the app while on the desktop the app context is behind the modal that shows up. The same mechanism is used with `FilePickers`.

On the WP8.1 when the app calls the API it's suspended, then the system opens the handler and when user completes the interaction with provided API, the app is resumed with a specific `Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind` enumeration as well as `detail` value that contains e.g. file handler or any other data returned by the API.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34889586/124797) by myself should solve your problem. [InAppBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) can be used to do the authentication. 
The advantage of [InAppBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) is it's cross-platform. In future, if you want to port your application to other platforms you have 1 less headache to deal with :-).